# Count occurrences in hourly time frame from given start end time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

I have a data set which contains starting/ending time of meetings in different meeting rooms (exported from meeting rooms calendar) for a period of several months. I would like to create heat map which will show utilization per hour in an average day (lets say Monday).
I've made a mock-up to show what I want as a result:
[Wanted mock-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tj3n.png)

This will be done using Plot.ly following this [Heatmap guide](https://help.plot.ly/make-a-heatmap/).

So far I have made dataframe for each day of the week and sort it by room name

```
RoomName    Start               End
Room1       18.5.2018 7:00      18.5.2018 19:00
Room1       6.7.2018 7:00        6.7.2018 19:00
Room1       13.7.2018 7:00      13.7.2018 19:00
Room1       20.7.2018 7:00      20.7.2018 19:00
Room1       27.7.2018 7:00      27.7.2018 19:00
Room1       3.8.2018 7:00        3.8.2018 19:00
Room1       29.6.2018 7:00      29.6.2018 19:00
Room1       22.6.2018 7:00      22.6.2018 19:00
Room2       29.6.2018 9:00      29.6.2018 11:00
Room2       15.6.2018 9:00      15.6.2018 10:30
Room2       17.8.2018 10:00     17.8.2018 11:30
...         ...                 ...
Room8       10.8.2018 7:00      10.8.2018 19:00
Room8       17.8.2018 7:00      17.8.2018 19:00
```

I am wondering how to process this data to create an average day and hourly intervals in that day which will contain the number of occurrences of certain room being booked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your frame is called `df`, it looks like you need to reindex it to get one row per 30 minutes of occupancy for each room (assuming this is the shortest length of booking possible). You can do this like so:

```
for col in ('Start', 'End'):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

bookings = []
for _, data in df.groupby(['RoomName', 'Start']):
    new_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(
        start=data['Start'].iloc[0], end=data['End'].iloc[0], freq='30Min'
    )

    data = data.set_index('Start').reindex(new_index).ffill()\
               .reset_index(drop=False).rename({'index': 'Time'}, axis='columns')\
               .drop('End', axis='columns')
    bookings.append(data)

occupied_times = pd.concat(bookings, ignore_index=True)
```

This then gives you, from the first few rows of your dataframe:

```
                   Time RoomName
0   2018-03-08 07:00:00    Room1
1   2018-03-08 07:30:00    Room1
2   2018-03-08 08:00:00    Room1
3   2018-03-08 08:30:00    Room1
4   2018-03-08 09:00:00    Room1
5   2018-03-08 09:30:00    Room1
6   2018-03-08 10:00:00    Room1
7   2018-03-08 10:30:00    Room1
8   2018-03-08 11:00:00    Room1
9   2018-03-08 11:30:00    Room1
10  2018-03-08 12:00:00    Room1
11  2018-03-08 12:30:00    Room1
12  2018-03-08 13:00:00    Room1
13  2018-03-08 13:30:00    Room1
14  2018-03-08 14:00:00    Room1
15  2018-03-08 14:30:00    Room1
16  2018-03-08 15:00:00    Room1
17  2018-03-08 15:30:00    Room1
18  2018-03-08 16:00:00    Room1
19  2018-03-08 16:30:00    Room1
20  2018-03-08 17:00:00    Room1
21  2018-03-08 17:30:00    Room1
22  2018-03-08 18:00:00    Room1
23  2018-03-08 18:30:00    Room1
24  2018-03-08 19:00:00    Room1
25  2018-05-18 07:00:00    Room1
26  2018-05-18 07:30:00    Room1
27  2018-05-18 08:00:00    Room1
28  2018-05-18 08:30:00    Room1
29  2018-05-18 09:00:00    Room1
..                  ...      ...
183 2018-07-27 11:00:00    Room1
184 2018-07-27 11:30:00    Room1
185 2018-07-27 12:00:00    Room1
186 2018-07-27 12:30:00    Room1
187 2018-07-27 13:00:00    Room1
188 2018-07-27 13:30:00    Room1
189 2018-07-27 14:00:00    Room1
190 2018-07-27 14:30:00    Room1
191 2018-07-27 15:00:00    Room1
192 2018-07-27 15:30:00    Room1
193 2018-07-27 16:00:00    Room1
194 2018-07-27 16:30:00    Room1
195 2018-07-27 17:00:00    Room1
196 2018-07-27 17:30:00    Room1
197 2018-07-27 18:00:00    Room1
198 2018-07-27 18:30:00    Room1
199 2018-07-27 19:00:00    Room1
200 2018-06-15 09:00:00    Room2
201 2018-06-15 09:30:00    Room2
202 2018-06-15 10:00:00    Room2
203 2018-06-15 10:30:00    Room2
204 2018-06-29 09:00:00    Room2
205 2018-06-29 09:30:00    Room2
206 2018-06-29 10:00:00    Room2
207 2018-06-29 10:30:00    Room2
208 2018-06-29 11:00:00    Room2
209 2018-08-17 10:00:00    Room2
210 2018-08-17 10:30:00    Room2
211 2018-08-17 11:00:00    Room2
212 2018-08-17 11:30:00    Room2
```